# Using AVAudioRecorder inside of AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder, audiokit

Is there a known way to convert an AVAudioRecorder object into an AKNode object?

My use case for this is that I have an application that is pulling an audio stream from a custom piece of bluetooth hardware. I've already written all the handlers for this, and the output of the hardware ends up as an AVAudioRecorder.

I'd like to make use of all the nicer visualisation of audio that AK offers - specifically the plotting of amplitude on a graph in my view as it is recorded, but to get it to work, it appears that I need to turn the AVAudioRecorder into an AKNode.

Is there an easy way to do this without going back through all the code that interfaces with the hardware and replacing it to use AKNode from the start?

I have gone through the documentation of AK and it doesn't seem possible at this time to use an existing AVAudioRecorder as a source node.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so. AVAudioPlayer is also unavailable, but we do have AVAudioPlayerNode. There is not a corresponding AVAudioRecorderNode.